# CodeIgniter 4 Session is destroyed after refreshing the website

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-4

My session is always destroyed after refreshing the page.

This is my setting.

```
app.sessionDriver = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler'
app.sessionCookieName = 'sippeg_session'
app.sessionExpiration = 0
app.sessionSavePath = 'ci_sessions'
app.sessionMatchIP = false
app.sessionTimeToUpdate = 300
app.sessionRegenerateDestroy = false
```

I don't have any code that leads to session_destroyed.

My session is still available before the redirect:

[image: Entered Session Data To The Database.]

But when I refresh the page, the session has gone:

[image: The Session Data Is Gone.]

Comment: @ilamengl I believe at the time when the OP posted the question, He/She didn't have enough rights/reputation to "inline images". [Why can't users with less than 10 reputation points add images while asking question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307503/7376590)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa noted thx!

Comment: Please consider closing the question by accepting the provided answer (if it did solve your problem) see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation:

[CodeIgniter 4 Session Preferences](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences)

> If `sessionExpiration` is set to `0`, the `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting
> set by PHP in session management will be used as-is (often the default
> value of `1440`). This needs to be changed in `php.ini` or via `ini_set()`
> as needed.

[Excerpt From The `php.ini` file (session.cookie_lifetime)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/2d3415a74ad33b98d433085ea09c0d63a85dcc90/php.ini-development#L1393)

```
; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
; https://php.net/session.cookie-lifetime
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
```

[Excerpt From The `php.ini` file (session.gc-maxlifetime)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/2d3415a74ad33b98d433085ea09c0d63a85dcc90/php.ini-development#L1439)

```
; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
; https://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

; NOTE: If you are using the subdirectory option for storing session files
;       (see session.save_path above), then garbage collection does *not*
;       happen automatically.  You will need to do your own garbage
;       collection through a shell script, cron entry, or some other method.
;       For example, the following script is the equivalent of setting
;       session.gc_maxlifetime to 1440 (1440 seconds = 24 minutes):
;          find /path/to/sessions -cmin +24 -type f | xargs rm
```

#### Solution:

Based on the fact that you normally don't have access to the `php.ini` file on [shared web hosting services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service) to configure the `session.gc_maxlifetime`, it would be more convenient to set that directly in the `.env` file at the root path of your project. I.e:

Instead of:

```
app.sessionExpiration = 0 ❌
```

Use this:

*The time is measured in seconds. 86400 = 24 hours.*

```
app.sessionExpiration = 86400 ✅
cookie.expires = 86400
```